# Trouble installing custom ROM in TWRCP (device unknown) getprop ro.product.device shows nothing

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, lineageos

I'm trying to flash a custom ROM on my Honor 5x, and it gone wrong. So I installed the old one back. Now I'm trying to re-install the new one, but when I try to install it from TWRCP, it says "This package is for device : kiwi; this device is ."
It looks like my device name has gone. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is usually a sign that your system partition has been erased... If you're using TWRP (Team Win Recovery Project) then you can check this by first mounting your system and then using the File Manager to navigate into system... You should see several folders and a file called Build.prop, this file holds your ro.product.device information

Comment: So I should override this file to set the ro.product.device info to "kiwi" right?

Comment: No, If you see the file then your system is fine, Try backing everything up and changing the ROM to not check the build.prop for device info... Usually if a ROM requires you to be on a specific device then it's dependent on your current system... You can extract the Zip file (ROM) and change the lines that check your device prior to installation. .. It'll be in `ROM.zip/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script`  and needs to be edited in notepad++ or Root Explorer ..Newer ROM's don't use the old updater-script but instead use the update-binary, this is harder to modify and outside the scope

Comment: So I guess I then need to disable MD5 verification for custom ROMs. Thanks